# Always require certain dependencies in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working on a `Backbone` project and I'm loading `jQuery`, `Underscore` and `Backbone` with **RequireJS**.

I find myself typing this pattern over and over again in all the modules:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) { ...
```

Is there a way or workaround to make these 3 libraries available to all modules without explicitly requiring them so I can concentrate on requiring extra things?

I though about loading this dependencies stack within script tags and use RequireJS for my modules and extra dependencies, but I'd lose the `JamJS` compile feature by having to concatenate jquery, underscore and backbone myself.

**EDIT:**

See [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate): They are using JamJS too but they don't require backbone,underscore,jquery on each file. Somehow it's available to all of them.

They require the `config.js` file within the markup with RequireJS. This exports require.config stuff and then delegates to `main.js`. Within main, then they have magically access to **Backbone**!

What happened in the middle?

Comment: try making a sandbox and then just requiring the sandbox

Comment: What do you mean by sandbox? Can you give more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a sandbox as mentioned in the comments. Here is a sample in coffee-script:

```
define [
  "core"
  "jquery"
  "extensions/backbone"
  "underscore"
], (core, $, backbone, underscore) ->

  util: 
    underscore: underscore
  mvc:
    Model: backbone.Model
    Collection: backbone.Collection
    View: backbone.View
    Events: backbone.Events
    Router: backbone.Router
```

This allows me to do

```
define ["sandbox"], (sandbox) -> class View extends sandbox.mvc.View
```

This is similar to the sandbox used in the [AuraJS project](https://github.com/aurajs/aura#sandbox) and an implementation of the [facade pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#facadepatternjavascript) which has the benefit that...

> It lets you expose the parts of a JavaScript library that are safe to
>   use instead of exposing the entire API. This is particularly useful
>   when working in teams.

Also, in the future if I want to extend all views from a BaseView class instead of directly from Backbone.View, I just have to change the reference in my sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can make globally accessible using the [SHIM Config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Example taken from there:

```
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
        //backbone.js
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
        //module value.
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
```

Comment: This leaves me with define([backbone], function() {}). Shim doesn't triggers automatically download. Even if I require Backbone from my root file (and Backbone is already donwloaded) I have to explicitly require them in all modules