# Calling require(['app']) Only Once

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

How can I call requireJS **require(['app'], function() {})**; only once at the beginning for the whole application so that any subsequent **require(["..."], function(...){})**; don't need to be wrapped within require(['app']?

This is my set up:

1) Load require.js

```
<script data-main="js/app.js" src="requirejs/require.min.js"></script>
```

2) Have app.js shims and basUrl configured properly.

```
requirejs.config({ 

  baseUrl: "scripts/js",

  paths: { 
    "jquery": "../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
    "modernizr": "../bower_components/modernizr/modernizr", 
    .
    . 
    .
  },
  shim: {
    "jquery.migrate": ['jquery'], 
    .
    .
    .
  }
});
```

3) Dynamically load JS on different pages:

```
// Home Page
require(['app'], function() {

    require(["jquery", "foundation", "foundation.reveal"], function ($, foundation, reveal){
         $(document).foundation(); 
    }); 
});


// Catalog Page
require(['app'], function() {

    require(["jquery", "lnav/LeftNavCtrl","controllers/ProductCtrl", "controllers/TabsCtrl"], function ($, NavCtrl, ProductCtrl, TabsCtrl){
        $(function() {
            NavCtrl.initLeftNav(); 
        });
    }); 
});
```

Unless I wrap with require(['app'], function()) each time I call require("...") to load external JS or AMD modules, the app is not initialized and I get JavaScript errors. The above code works but it's not very efficient.

Is there a way to start my requireJS app before I try loading scripts?

I tried calling at the very beginning right after I load require.min.js:

```
require(["app"], function (app) {
    app.run();
});
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Always require certain dependencies in RequireJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563348/always-require-certain-dependencies-in-requirejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no provisions in RequireJS to ensure that a specific module is always loaded before any other module is loaded, other than having your first module load the rest. What you are trying to do is share your first module among multiple pages so it cannot perform the work of loading what is specific to each page.

One way you can work around this is simply to load `app.js` with a regular `script` element:

```
<script src="requirejs/require.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Then the next `script` element can start your application without requiring `app.js`:

```
<script>
   require(["jquery", "foundation", "foundation.reveal"], function ($, foundation, reveal){
     $(document).foundation(); 
   }); 
</script>
```

This is actually how I've decided to launch my modules in the applications I'm working on right now. True, it is not as optimized as it could be because of the extra network round-trip, but in the case of the applications I'm working on, they are still in *very* heavy development, and I prefer to leave this optimization for later.

Note that *generally* you don't want to use `script` to load RequireJS modules but your `app.js` is not a real module as it does not call `define`, so this is okay.

Another option would be to use a building tool like Grunt, Gulp, Make or something else and create one `app.js` per page and have each page load its own `app.js` file. This file would contain the configuration *and* the first `require` call to load the modules specific to your page.

Comment: I agree it's not the most optimal solution since it's loading app.js twice but for now seems to be working. Will use this until I find a better solution.